# Is it possible to analyse a very large 3D input volume at once with a 3D CNN?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I would like to use a 3D convolutional network on a 2000x2000x2000 volume for segmentation. I know I can break the volume into chunks that can fit in VRAM, but I was wondering if there was a way to analyze the entire 3D volume at once.

Comment: Hi, welcome to AI.se! You'll probably have better luck with this question over at [DataScience](http://datascience.stackexchange.com) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).